# Python sum of list not adding the first and last

Tags: python

```
def sumfirstlast(num):
new_list = list(num)
for sum in new_list:
    total = int(new_list.pop(0)) + int(new_list.pop())
return(total)


number = input("Input number")
display = sumfirstlast(number)
print(display)
```

Why when i type 43682 it return 11 instead of 6 ? Since im adding the first and last number in the list

Comment: You need to convert your strings to integers, right now you are doing string concatenation

Comment: oml simple stuff ! Thanks totally missed that !

Comment: It's bad practice to use `sum` as a variable name, since there's already a builtin function called `sum()`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum 
(this is not the cause of this particular bug, but it is a common beginner mistake that can easily lead to hard to understand bugs)

Comment: You problem is that you've got it in a `for` loop - you add the first and last elements together and remove them from the list, then do it again. So instead of adding the 4 and 2, you add the 3 and 8 together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `total = int(new_list[0])) + int(new_list[len(new_list) - 1])` should work.

Comment: Hello this works ! But can i ask what does this code mean ? int(new_list[len(new_list) - 1]) Sorry i'm pretty new to python and im having a hard time with list :(

Comment: `new_list[-1]` is a better way to get the last element of the list.

Comment: @RobWatts can i ask why new_list.pop() doesn't work in this case ?

Comment: `new_list.pop()` will work but modifies `new_list` in the process which isn't really necessary and can make things confusing

Comment: @RobWatts I see the change, don't want to basically copy your answer though

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the unnecessary `for` loop, combined with modifying the list:

```
for sum in new_list:
    total = int(new_list.pop(0)) + int(new_list.pop())
```

If `new_list` is `['4', '3', '6', '8', '2']`, on the first iteration the total is correctly set to 6. However, you're still in the loop - total will be set once again, this time adding 3 and 8 together.

So your method should instead just add the first and last elements together, without any loop:

```
total = int(new_list[0]) + int(new_list[-1])
```

Most of the time you should be getting items from a list using indexes, rather than with `pop()`. `pop` is primarily for removing items from the list; it only returns the item removed as a convenience.